# Указать, что в ссылке, в конкретном месте будут числа

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

В ссылке типа : `http://localhost:8080/api/departments/ЛЮБОЕ ЧИСЛО/edit?` может быть любое число

Какое именно число - заранее я не знаю. Думал, что можно написать при помощи регулярного выражения, но не вышло

```
//http://localhost:8080/api/departments/10/edit?

if (uri === `http://localhost:8080/api/departments/` + /\d/ + `/edit?`) {
        return new EditDepartmentPage();
    }
```

if - возвращает false. Возможно ли написать такое с регулярным выражением или каким-то другим способом?

***Пишу на чистом js***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

может такое условие?

```
if(uri.match(/http:\/\/localhost:8080\/api\/departments\/[\d]+\/edit\?/))
```

Comment: Да! Вы абсолютно правы. Большое спасибо за помощь!

Comment: \d не нужно в [], а так же вместо match используйте test, если вам не нужно будет получать число.